# How do I add several columns at once in kdb?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Somehow, I can only find examples that show how to add one column.

So I have written this code, which works, but I know there is a much better way to do this:
table t already exists with columns filled with data, and I need to add new columns that are initially null.

```
 t: update column1:` from t;
 t: update column2:` from t;
 t: update column3:` from t;
 t: update column4:` from t;
```

I tried making it a function:

```
 colNames:`column1`column2`column3`column4;
 t:{update x:` from t}each colNamesList;
```

But this only added one column and called it x.

Any suggestions to improve this code will be greatly appreciated.  I have to add a lot more than just 4 columns and my code is very long because of this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various ways to achieve this....

```
q)newcols:`col3`col4;

q)@[tab;newcols;:;`]
col1 col2 col3 col4
-------------------
a    1
b    2
c    3
```

Can also specify different types

```
q)@[tab;newcols;:;(`;0N)]
col1 col2 col3 col4
-------------------
a    1
b    2
c    3
```

Or do a functional update

```
q)![`tab;();0b;newcols!count[newcols]#enlist (),`]
`tab
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough reply! Functional update I have used, but what is the function with the @[] called?  I'd like to know the name of it so I can read more about it.

Comment: It's the "apply" function (in conjunction with q doing some helpful things under the covers - such as filling the atomic ` out to the same length as the table)

http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/functions#Functional_Forms_of_Amend